# How to determine whether a partition is a LUKS partition from its mountpoint?

Tags: bash, mount, encryption, luks

I'm aware of being able to use the `cryptsetup isLuks` command to find out whether a partition is a LUKS container. I want to be able to use this command with the mountpoint of the LUKS container for the case that I cannot be sure that I know the partition's device name, how can I do this in one command?

For example, I have a Luks container at `/dev/sda2`, I open it with

```
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 vault
```

Then I mount the container with

```
$ mount /dev/mapper/vault /mountpoint
```

At this point I would like to know whether `/mountpoint` is a Luks container

```
$ cryptsetup isLuks -v /dev/sda2
Command successful.
$ cryptsetup isLuks -v /mountpoint
Command failed with code 15: Block device required
$ cryptsetup isLuks -v /dev/mapper/vault
Command failed with code 22: Device /dev/mapper/vault is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Normally I'd use `lsblk` to get the block device of a mountpoint, but this returns the `/dev/mapper/vault` path.

```
└─sda2   8:8    0   9.3G  0 part
  └─vault 252:0    0   9.3G  0 crypt /mountpoint
```

If I could resolve `/dev/mapper/vault` to `/dev/sda2` somehow, I would be able to use command substitution inside the `cryptsetup isLuks` command.

It would be great to find something more elegant than using `awk` or something to parse the output of `mount`, but if that's the only way then it works I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem to. Solved like this.

```
lsblk -sJp | jq -r --arg dsk "/dev/mapper/disk_name" '.blockdevices | .[] | select(.name == $dsk) | .children | .[0] | .name'
```

Return e.g. `/dev/sda2`

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  It's a little long, but making a bash function would simplify it:

```
cryptsetup isLuks -v `df /mountpoint | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1;}'`
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the `/dev/mapper/vault` path from `df` so I get the `Command failed with code 22: Device /dev/mapper/vault is not a valid LUKS device.` error. (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: “Adding a check (…) is left as an exercise for the reader.” sounds *really* condescending and unproductive to me. Please add either an example how one could do that or at least a link to a question covering the topic. The same goes for making a `bash` function – if you deem it useful in this particular case you should show how it’s done.

Comment: @dessert or I just remove that part.

Comment: @Arronical since `/dev/mapper` is used, does that mean that LVM is involved?

Comment: `awk 'END{print $1}'` saves you the `tail` call.

Comment: @dessert good to know.

Comment: @RonJohn unfortunately not, it uses the same device mapping system but the commands to query LVM such as lvl don't work.

Answer (score 1):

someone mentioned using `lsblk`

This is a relatively easy way but only if you do

```
alias lsblk2='lsblk -o type,name,label,partlabel,size,fstype,model,serial,wwn,uuid'
```

Then the output from lsblk will have much extra useful information, and the `FSTYPE` will show `crypto_LUKS` and then show the resulting partitions underneath.  And you'll also have the disk model and serial number to reference which I find useful making heads and tails of things.

`man lsblk` and add any options after the `-o` that you may find make it more useful for yourself.

I think this way... getting a simple visible tree list of all disks that linux currently sees... is the most straight forward way with least typing to know which disks/partitions are luks encrypted,  will show up as `crypto_LUKS` at least that's what I see using RHEL 7.9.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```bsh
for part in $(lsblk -o NAME -ln | grep -E '^[^loop]'); do
    if cryptsetup isLuks /dev/$part 2> /dev/null; then
        lsblk /dev/$part -ln -o MOUNTPOINT
    fi
done
```

The `lsblk` command had only the `NAME` option, so we will only get the name of the partitions in the system. The `-ln` also quit the title and the tree form, so is a pure list. The `grep` command is optional, it will skip checking the loop partitions created by snap. Then another `lsblk` to the partition detected as LUKS.

It's tricky, but LUKS and `cryptsetup` works with partitions, not mountpoints. If you are going to use it inside a script, you can create it as a function for better practice.